# Reverse iterate over a std::vector with forward iterators

Tags: c++

If I have a function which takes a `std::vector<T>::const_iterator` called begin and a `std::vector<T>::const_iterator` called end, is it possible for me to iterate over it in a backwards direction?

**UPDATE**

I can't change the function signature, which is like this:

```
void func(Foo::const_iterator begin, Foo::const_iterator end) 
{
   ...
}
```

and called with:

```
func(foo.begin(), foo.end());
```

which I also can't change

Comment: `vector<T>::const_iterator` is a RandomAccessIterator, not a ForwardIterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have misunderstood the question, but do you just need:

```
while (begin != end) {
    --end;
    // do something with *end
}
```

If you need an iterator that goes backwards, ipc's answer gives you one.

In practice with `vector` you could probably get away with `while (begin != end--)`, but don't be tempted. It's undefined behavior to decrement an iterator in the case where it's at the start of the vector (i.e. when it's equal to the result of `vector::begin()`).

This code requires at least a BidirectionalIterator. Fortunately, `vector` has a RandomAccessIterator, which is even better.

If you genuinely only had a ForwardIterator, then you'd have to iterate over the range and store the iterator values somewhere (like a `stack`), and then use them in reverse order:

```
std::stack<Foo::const_iterator> iterators;
while (begin != end) {
    iterators.push(begin);
    ++begin;
}
while (!iterators.empty()) {
    Foo::const_iterator i = iterators.top();
    // do something with *i
    iterators.pop();
}
```

This code requires at least a ForwardIterator (it will not work with a mere InputIterator).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.

```
template <typename Foo>
void test(typename Foo::const_iterator begin,
          typename Foo::const_iterator end)
{
  std::reverse_iterator<typename Foo::const_iterator>
    rbegin(end),
    rend(begin);
  std::copy(rbegin, rend, std::ostream_iterator<typename std::iterator_traits<typename Foo::const_iterator>::value_type>(std::cout));
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6};
  test<std::vector<int> >(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

Comment: You can name the reverse iterator type slightly more concisely, it's `std::vector<T>::const_reverse_iterator`.

Comment: @SteveJessop That's right in this case. But if you have a `Foo` you may not want to rely on that.

Comment: @ipc: true, if `Foo` is not a ReversibleContainer then you can't rely on it. And if you take the iterator type rather than the element type as your template argument then it's not available.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `std::reverse_iterator`. It is also a good idea not
to specify the type of the iterator explicitly. Use a template
argument instead.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename BidirectionalIterator>
void x(BidirectionalIterator b, BidirectionalIterator e) {
  std::reverse_iterator<BidirectionalIterator> rb(e), re(b);
  std::for_each(rb, re, 
                [](typename BidirectionalIterator::reference x) 
                { std::cout << x << std::endl;});
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};
  x(begin(v), end(v));
  return 0;
}
```